# Showing school logo in bootstrap well

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

so is there a nicer way to show the school logo in a well? Like how can I stick it to the right upper corner not inline with the text?

```
<div class = "well well-lg" style="background-color: #F2F2F2;">
    <img class ="m-a-1 m-y-1" style="padding: 20px 0; display: inline-block;">
    M.Sc. in Computer Sciences.
    University of Wisconsin-Madison, Madison, WI, USA.
    Graduated in May 2016.
        <img src="./assets/img/UW.png" alt="" style="height:100px; width:100px;"> </img>
    </span>
</div>
```

Here's what I see:
[image]

Also I have tried the following but still doesn't look as nice:

```
<div class = "well well-lg" style="background-color: #F2F2F2;">
    <img  class = "m-y-1" src="./assets/img/sharif.png" alt="" style="height:100px; width:100px;"> </img>
    <span class ="m-a-1 m-y-1" style="padding: 20px 0; display: inline-block;">
    M.Sc. in Computer Engineering <br/>Majored in Computer Architecture.
    Sharif University of Technology, Tehran, Iran. </br>
    Graduated in June 2011.
    </span>
</div>
```

[image]

Turns out I am being super unclear. I want the image to be like the second image in this question however vertically aligned in the middle. The following code puts the image above the text:

```
<div class = "well well-lg" style="background-color: #F2F2F2;">

    <span class ="m-a-1 m-y-1" style="padding: 20px 0; display: inline-block;">
        <img  class = "m-y-1" src="./assets/img/sharif.png" alt="" style="height:100px; width:100px; display: inline-block; vertical-align: middle;">
        <p>
        M.Sc. in Computer Engineering <br/>Majored in Computer Architecture.
        Sharif University of Technology, Tehran, Iran. </br>
        Graduated in June 2011.
        </p>
    </span>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: What do you mean nicer way? Do you mean aesthetically? Kind of opinion-based

Comment: Just omit one dimension (width or height), if you mean disproportioning.

Comment: set a width only - let height be auto. By upper right do you mean positioned absolutely? Why are you closing your img tag that way? Close it like this `<img src="path/image.jpg" alt="">` or `<img src="path/image.jpg" alt="" />`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So first off, there are a couple things wrong with your code.

1. You have an opening `<img>` tag and you're trying to close it with a `</span>`. I assume you meant for that to be a `<span>`.
2. `<img>` tag's are not closed by `</img>`. You need to do `<img />`.

Now to fix your problem, just add `display: flex; align-items: center;` to your `<div>`.

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class = "well well-lg" style="background-color: #F2F2F2; display: flex; align-items: center;">
    <img class = "m-y-1" src="http://xaonon.dyndns.org/logos/portal/aperture_science.png" alt="" style="width: 100px; height: auto; padding-right: 10px;" />
    <span class ="m-a-1 m-y-1" style="padding: 20px 0; display: inline-block;">
    M.Sc. in Computer Engineering <br/>Majored in Computer Architecture.
    Sharif University of Technology, Tehran, Iran. <br />
    Graduated in June 2011.
    </span>
</div>
```

[**JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/ab23pLdw/4/)

You can learn more about `flexbox` [here](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/).

```
<div class = "well well-lg img-rounded" style="background-color: #F2F2F2; display: flex; align-items: center;">
    <img class = "m-y-1" src="./assets/img/sharif.png" alt="" style="width: 100px; height: auto; padding-right: 10px; padding-left: 10px;" />
    <span class ="m-a-1 m-y-1" style="padding: 20px 0; display: inline-block;">
        M.Sc. in Computer Engineering <br/>Majored in Computer Architecture.
        Sharif University of Technology, Tehran, Iran. </br>
        Graduated in June 2011.
    </span>
</div>
```

Works as expected:
[image]

Comment: how can I change it so that it like the second image shown? the vertical align doesn't work for me. I have used middle but it is not centered vertically. I want it to be in the left hand side as shown

Comment: Did you look at my fiddle? If you're experience a specific problem please create a fiddle yourself and let me know how I can help :)

Comment: you fiddle puts the image above the whole text. I want it say be in the left as shown in the second photo but aligned centered.

Comment: As you can see here: https://jsfiddle.net/ab23pLdw/2/ The image is vertically aligned with the text. So I'm not too sure what you're talking about.

Comment: I decided to update to `flexbox`. Please see updated fiddle in answer. https://jsfiddle.net/ab23pLdw/4/